# Remove unrelated files from Git?

Tags: python, git, github, terminal, pycharm

Sorry if this is worded badly or has a simple solution but I'm completely new to all this. So I was working on a GitHub pages site in pycharm and used terminal to push to files to GitHub, but I think I messed up something with the directory, and my files in other pycharm projects in separate folders are now highlighted in red. I also get prompted to push to GitHub when creating a new file which didn't happen before.

To clarify, inside a "pycharm projects" folder are separate "git hub pages" and "some project" folders. Anyone know where I can begin to fix this?

Comment: Where is your .git folder located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first and clone your GitHub page repository again, and import it in PyCharm.

Then modify a file, and check the push is working again as expected.

Finally, report the modifications you were doing in your original cloned repository into this new clone.